# Comparison Micro Chart on a Generic Tile

Tags: charts, sapui5, tile

To display a comparison micro chart inside a generic tile (like in below link), there is a limitation of 3 rows displayed in the chart. 
[Sample: Comparison Micro Chart on a Generic Tile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.suite.ui.microchart.sample.ComparisonMicroChartInGenericTile/preview)

Is it possible to overcome that limitation? Please provide some directions on how to achieve more than 3 rows in comparison chart inside the generic tile.

Comment: Instead of **Generic Tile** you can use **Custom Tile**. 
**Generic Tile** - You have to follow the structure
**Custom Tile**  - You can customized look and feel.

Comment: @inizio Unfortunately, [sap.m.CustomTile is already deprecated](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.CustomTile) as of version 1.50. Both, the the API reference and [Fiori Design Guideline](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/tile/#donts) recommend to stick with GenericTile.